# Gray image for buttons which is disale on toolbar in MFC application

Tags: mfc-feature-pack

I have a problem in a MFC application
When I change DPI of windows 7 then I log off my computer
When windows is started, i open my application 
My problem as bellow :
The button of toolbar Which is disabled was not grayed image
The image of this button is not grayed.
I have found many website about DPI and MFC but i did not find any articles for this problem

Can members of stackoverflow help me ?
Thank you very much.